# Observable.onError handler does not prevent exception to kill the app

Tags: flutter, dart-async, rxdart

**UPDATED THE CODE**

I'm tired from debugging these error with no result 
anyone know what the wrong ???!?!?!

when the added Stream emits normal events it's works fine but when emitting error it's handled by the onErorr method and a strange error happened as you see in the StackTrace.

```
test("Testing the Stream", () async {

 final _categoriesInfosSubject = new PublishSubject<String>();
 var errorThrown = false;

 Observable<String>  categories$ = _categoriesInfosSubject.stream;
 categories$.listen(any, onError: (err){ print("ErrorHappened"); errorThrown = true;});

 await _categoriesInfosSubject.addStream(
  Observable.error(Error()),
 );
 await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), (){});
 expect(errorThrown , true);

});
```

```
ErrorHappened
dart:async                                              _Completer.completeError
package:rxdart/src/subjects/subject.dart 101:19         Subject.addStream. 
<fn>
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
dart:async                                              _StreamImpl.listen
package:rxdart/src/streams/error.dart 25:30             ErrorStream.listen
package:rxdart/src/observables/observable.dart 1729:20  Observable.listen
package:rxdart/src/subjects/subject.dart 94:12          Subject.addStream
test\home_screen\home_bloc.dart 77:35                   main.<fn>

Instance of 'Error'
```

Comment: `asynchronous gap` only means that the stack trace is not continuous because an async callback was executed. This is unrelated to the cause of the error, this is only a hint to make the stack trace easier to understand.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer So what's the wrong with this test.. if I add assertion after 2 seconds it's not get to it. and debugging is not showing me anything !!!

Comment: Not sure what you expect. You mean there should not be exception output because you registered an `onError` handler?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer exactly!!